# Angular. Как отформатировать денежную сумму?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Исходное число 1000(значение value[4]), на выходе должно быть $1,000.00
Прошу совета

```
documentCode += '</tr>';
angular.forEach($scope.agregateApplicationsData().rows, function(value, key){
        documentCode += '<tr>' + addLine(value[0]) + addLine(value[1]) + 
        addLine(value[2]) + addLine(value[3]) + addLine(value[4]) +
        addLine(value[5]) + addLine(value[6]) + '</tr>';
      });
documentCode += '</table>';
```

Comment: фильтр `number` вполне подходит, нужно только при выводе добавить символ валюты

Comment: а что делает приведенный блок кода? что за функция _addLine_ и какой смысл вообще собирать сырой html в ангуляре?

Comment: генерация документов для печати

Comment: [filter:currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй [`$filter("currency")(value\[4\])`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Результат: `$1,000.00`